# I am travelling to Iceland from Mumbai and have to change flights at Heathrow

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, transit-visas, lhr, iceland

I am travelling to Iceland from Mumbai and have to change flights at Heathrow. From terminal 4 to terminal 2.

Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Are you an Indian citizen ?

Comment: Yes I am an Indian citizen

Comment: Your valid Schengen visa exempts you from the UK airside transit visa requirement. See the linked question for details.

Comment: She needs to check baggage again from t4 to t2 means she needs to clear immigration at Heathrow

Answer (score -2):

As an Indian citizen, you [will need](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/india/transit/no) a [Direct Airside Transit visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa).

Comment: First, this is wrong. She has a Schengen visa, is traveling to a Schengen country, and is therefore exempt from the requirement (at least, when remaining airside). Second, we prefer to mark duplicate questions as duplicates rather than add yet more answers to identical questions.

Comment: Ok so I am changing flights at the airport and will need to check in baggage again from terminal 4 to terminal 2. So will that mean I am airside?

Comment: @MichaelHampton If she has a schengen visa, why would it matter if she was airside or not? Couldn't she even (theoretically) enter the UK? (Not a rhetorical question, I'm actually wondering.)

Comment: @Fiksdal, the UK is not in Schengen.

Comment: @rojomoke That was an easy answer. I  had thought all Western European countries were members.

Comment: @ fiksdal not all EU countries are in schengen zone, also non EU countries like Switzerland, Norway and Iceland are in schengen area